# Checking directory for file with certain extension

Tags: ruby, file, directory, file-extension

I am trying to check whether a directory entered through the command line contains files with a certain file extension. For example, if I have a folder "Folder1" with another folder in it "Folder 2" and Folder2 contains several files, "test.asm", "test.vm", "test.tst". I am taking either a directory or a file through the command line like this

```
ruby translator.rb Folder1/Folder2
```

or

```
ruby translator.rb Folder1/Folder2/test.vm
```

What I'm trying to do is error checking. I already have checks for whether the input is a folder and now I need to check whether the folder actually contains a .vm file. 
What I've done so far is this:

```
require 'pathname'

pn = Pathname.new(ARGV[0])

if ARGV.size != 1
    puts "Proper usage is: ruby vmtranslator.rb file_directory\file.vm \nOR \nruby vmtranslator.rb file_directory\ where file_directory has multiple vm files test".split("\n")
elsif !pn.exist? && !pn.directory?
    puts "Something is wrong with the file"
    puts "Either try another file or check the file extension"
elsif pn.directory? && pn.children(false).extname.include?('.vm')
    puts "this should print if Folder1 is the folder, but not if Folder2 is.."
    vm_file1 = File.open("OPEN FILES WITH .vm AS EXTENSION)
elsif pn.exist? || pn.file?
    puts "this is right"
    vm_file = File.open(ARGV[0], "r")
    asm_file = File.new(ARGV[0].sub('.vm', '.asm'), "w")
end
```

So what that should do is check whether there is only 1 argument first, if so, then it checks if it's a file or directory else it outputs an error, then what I'm doing is checking if it's a directory. If so, I need to check if the directory actually contains .vm files. I tried `pn.each_child {|f| f.extname == '.vm'}` but that only checks the first value before it returns true. Is there any easier way to check the whole array before returning true, other than just setting some boolean?

Some of the code up there isn't done, I'm just asking if there is any way to check a directory for a file of a certain extension. I can't find anything with my searches so far.

Comment: consider using arguments like -f filename and -d directory and using optparse to parse them. The reason this isn't a good question is that your logic is too convoluted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = ARGV[0]

proc = ->(f) { puts "doing something with #{f.path}" }

if Dir.exists?(str)
  Dir.glob(File.join(str, File.join('**', '*.vm'))).each do |entry|
    proc[File.open(entry)]
  end
elsif File.exists?(str) && File.extname(str) == '.vm'
  proc[File.open(str)]
else
  puts "couldn't do anything with #{str}"
end
```

Comment: I like the Dir.glob line, but I'm not really understanding what you are doing with the `.each(&proc)` there. Could you explain further?

Comment: The `&` operator converts a `Proc` into a `block` so `each` can do something with it. It's just a throwaway example procedure—I just wanted to quickly "do the same thing for each file entry". You could just as easily call a "real" method using each entry as an argument.

Comment: @snowe2010: but `&` does *a lot* in Ruby: http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: Ok, after trying your code, it looks like `File.join('**', '*.vm')` takes recursive directories. I actually don't want it to return true for Folder1 if that folder doesn't actually contain any .vm files. Would I just remove the ** there?

Comment: @snowe2010: `Dir.glob(File.join(str, '*.vm'))` will only match files in the `str` directory

Comment: Yeah I still can't get that to work. I'm trying to do this `if Dir.glob(File.join(str, '*.vm')).size > 0`, but that is definitely not working and I can't figure out why. Also I read the whole webpage you showed and I think I understand the proc line. The only thing on that line I don't understand is the `(f)`

Comment: @snowe2010: `->(f){}` defines an anonymous function that takes one argument (`f`) and does nothing.

Comment: So `proc[File.open(entry)]` opens the file and also prints `doing something with #{f.path}` where f is the file that has been opened?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dir["Folder1/Folder2/*.vm"].empty?
```

will return `false` if there are any `.vm` files in `Folder1/Folder2`.

Comment: I didn't really specify, but the directory could also just be Folder2/blah.vm, would I just be able to do `Dir[pn + "/*.vm"].empty?` ?

Comment: I tried the above, and I can't get that to work. The problem is, that the user can enter any path, and I need to check if the path actually contains a .vm file, or if it is a .vm file, and if it doesn't/isn't it needs to output an error.

Comment: I was just showing the method by which you might solve the problem, not solving your whole problem for you. `Dir[str]`, equivalent to `Dir.glob(str, 0)`, will return an array of matches. `empty?` then checks if the resulting array is empty (i.e. no matches were found). In other people's responses, `"**"` in `str` matches 0 or more intervening directories, so `"a/**/d"` matches `/a/d` and `/a/b/c/d`. Single asterisk matches non-separators. People were using `File.join` for compatibility - it just inserts a slash (or backslash), does no magic by itself.

Comment: Yeah I see that, but I'm still unable to get anything anyone has said to work. I understand the principles I just can't get it to work. `Dir[File.join(str, "*.vm"))` does not return an array of the files in the folder if the folder is two deep. In other words, `Dir[File.join(str, File.join("**", "*.vm"))` works because it checks the second directory, but it fails because it also checks the parent. I need to only check the directory that the string ends in. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'pathname'

def directory_has_vm_files?(path)
  Dir.glob(path.join('*.vm')).size > 0
end

unless ARGV[0]
  puts %{
    Proper usage is:

    ruby vmtranslator.rb file_directory or file.vm

    OR

    ruby vmtranslator.rb file_directory
    where file_directory has multiple vm files
  }
else
  path = Pathname.new(ARGV[0])

  if path.exist?
    if path.file?
      if File.extname(path) == '.vm'
        puts "Valid VM file"
      else
        puts "Not a VM file"
      end
    else
      if directory_has_vm_files?(path)
        puts "Valid Directory - contains vm files"
      else
        puts "#{path} does not contain any VM file"
      end
    end
  else
    puts "Invalid path"
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this and I can't get the directory_has_vm_files? method to work. It seems that path.join function won't work that way. pje's function seems to work, but I don't understand his very well either.